# Can't Add ComboBox to Radgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2012, telerik, radgrid

[View][1]I'm  creating a bounded radgrid, i was trying to add bounded combobox to rad grid, but column is showing.combobox are't show.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

You can find various samples for using RadGrid in combination with combo/dropdownlist provided in [this post](https://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-have-dropdownlist-and-textbox-inside-a-radgrid#A9aPQyI5vE-ENWi8clmy6Q).

Answer (score 0):

First: you need to be a little more explicit in your question or problem.
Maybe adding a little code or images will help us understand more.

From what i understand, you have a radgridview and you want a specific column to have a combobox as a type.

You can do something like this:

```
//define a GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn
GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn column = new GridViewMultiComboBoxColumn();
column.Name = "Your column name";
column.HeaderText = "The header text you want to have";
column.FieldName = "Field name, maybe you have a class read from a db";
column.DataSource = ds; //here you need to define your datasource for your combobox
column.ValueMember = "Value"; //depends on what you receive from datasource
column.DisplayMember = "Value"; //depends on what you receive from datasource 

//add the column to your radgridview
gridView.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(column);
```